How do i fetch the FCM campaign details in my app?
I develop an app, there are two riles admin and users. When any campaign is published the details of all the campaign is fetched in to the admin side app. So is that any method todo this in the flutter app. I read documentation but i didn't understand that. So how to implement this?
